# The program needs to show the variable with greater first digit

Tags: c

The program needs to show an number which has a greater first digit, which works, only if the numbers of digits are the same on both variables. Try with these numbers 4506 29985, it should show 4506, but the program shows 29985, the program was written in C language.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int disassembly1 (int a) 
{
    while (a>=10) 
    {
        a /= 10;
    }

    return a;
}

int disassembly2 (int b) 
{
    while (b>=10) 
    {
        b /= 10;
    }

    return b;
}

int main ()
{
    int A1, B1, a, b;

    printf("Int 2 numbers:\n");
    scanf_s("%d %d", &A1, &B1);

    a = A1;
    b = B1;

    disassembly1(A1);
    disassembly2(B1);

    if (a > b || ((a == b) && (A1 > B1)))
        printf("%d\n", A1);
    else
        printf("%d\n", B1);

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Why did you write the same function twice?

Comment: The `disassembly` functions return something. Perhaps you want to do something with it?

Comment: You need to _debug_ your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `disassembly1` and `disassembly2` are the same function and should not written twice.

Second and more important, the function `disassembly` returns the first digit, but you need to store it in a variable.

A working code (with a few changes):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int disassembly(int a) 
{
    while (a>=10) 
    {
        a /= 10;
    }
    return a;
}
int main()
{
    int a, b, a_digit, b_digit;
    printf("Int 2 numbers:\n");
    scanf_s("%d %d", &a, &b);
    a_digit = disassembly(a);
    b_digit = disassembly(b);
    if (a_digit > b_digit || ((a_digit == b_digit) && (a > b)))
        printf("%d\n", a);
    else
        printf("%d\n", b);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Also, the name `disassembly` does not match the function meaning. I would suggest to change it to something like `get_first_digit`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not read the values returned from the functions, leaving variables `a` & `b` unchanged.

Change:

```
disassembly1(A1);
disassembly2(B1);
```

To:

```
a = disassembly1(A1);
b = disassembly2(B1);
```

Other suggestions:

define and use a single instance of function:  `int disassembly(int x);` and call it twice.

```
a = disassembly(A1);
b = disassembly(B1);
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a much simpler version (this is matlab/octave, but can easily be ported to c)

```
a = 4506;
b = 29985;
isAbigger = floor(a/10^(floor(log10(a)))) > floor(b/10^(floor(log10(b))));
```